# How to add another condition in a for loop

Tags: python

I'm writing a program that creates events in the google calendar.

My python code is connected to MySQL database.

Every company has 3 employees assigned to it. If the first employee is busy, it will check for the second employee, if he's busy too, it will check for the third one.

The code works, but the company name goes in the `event['description']`. My code only checks for `event['summary']` which is represented by the employees. So If first employee is busy, check next one and so on..

My problem is that If I add **another** appointment for the **same** company, and if one of the employee is still free, IT WILL add the event. So I will see in the calendar 2 events for the same company at the time.

What I want is that if the company (`event_description`) == `event['description']` then dont create the event

**I tried something that didnt work :**

```
        currentEmployees = []
        found_match = False
        for event in events:
            currentEmployees.append(event['summary'])

        for i in range(3):
            event_summary = row[i+1]
            if event_inspecteur not in currentEmployees and event['description'] != event_fabricant :
                event = {
                    'summary': event_summary,
                    'location': event_location,
                    'description': event_description,
                    'start': {
                        'dateTime': event_start,
                        'timeZone': 'America/New_York',
                    },
                    'end': {
                        'dateTime': event_end,
                        'timeZone': 'America/New_York',
                    },
                    'attendees': [
                        {'email': event_email},
                    ],
                    'reminders': {
                        'useDefault': True,
                    },
                }
                print('Nouveau RDV creer')
                event = service.events().insert(calendarId='primary', body=event).execute()
                break

            else:
                print("La plage horraire est deja prise par : ")
                start = event['start'].get('dateTime', event['start'].get('date'))
                print(start, "Fabricant: " + event['description'], "/// " + "Inspecteur: " + event['summary'], "/// " + "Location: " + event['location'])
                pass
```

This line           `if event_inspecteur not in currentEmployees and event['description'] != event_fabricant :`  gave me this error below because I added `and event['description'] != event_fabricant :`

```
    if event_inspecteur not in currentEmployees and event['description'] != event_fabricant :
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'event' referenced before assignment
```

Comment: use event_description instead of event['description'] which u are assigning later inside the loop

Comment: As an aside, you appear to be mixing multiple naming conventions. It's best to just stick to `lower_case_with_underscores` for functions and variables.

Comment: @Luv event_description is my variable, event['description'] is the description of the event in the google calendar

Answer (score 0):

I just had to add another list.

```
    currentEmployees = []
    currentCompany = []
    found_match = False
    for event in events:
        currentEmployees.append(event['summary'])
        currentCompany.append(event['description'])

    for i in range(3):
        event_inspecteur = row[i+1]
        if event_inspecteur not in currentEmployees and event_fabricant not in currentCompany:
```